# set precision of overloaded operator <<

Tags: c++

I have overloaded the operator << to print data about a product in my program.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Product& p) {
    return out << '\t' << (int)p.code << "\tR$ " << p.price << '\t' << p.name;
}
```

but I need to change the precision of p.price to 2 decimal digits.

I already tried **out.setprecision(2)**, but it didin't work.

This is the part that prints a product:

```
cout << this->items[i] << endl;
```

and the result:

`253 R$ 13   Paçoca`

I need it to be `R$ 13,00`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just chain it: `... << setprecision(2) << ...`!

Comment: `cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << p.price;`

Comment: If you really meant the `253 ` (which is the value of `(int)p.code`) should also go away, just don't output it.

Comment: haha, I didn't explained well. 
I was saying just about the money part.

Comment: @LuizEduardoF. I've updated the answer to give some additional reasoning why `out.setprecision(2)` dosen't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have overloaded the operator << to print data about a product in my program. ...

You can just insert it into the `std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream& out, ...)` function call chain:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const Product& p) {
    return out << '\t' << (int)p.code << "\tR$ " 
               << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) 
               << p.price << '\t' << p.name;
}
```

May be you'll also need to adapt some localization settings to get a `,` (instead of a `.`) to get your decimal point separator right.

> I already tried **out.setprecision(2)**, but it didin't work.

The reason is that `setprecision(int)` is not a method of the `std::ostream` interface, but a global function composed from the following bits (stolen from MinGW GCC 4.6.2 implementation):

```
struct _Setprecision { int _M_n; };

// This is what's actually called (both functions below):
inline _Setprecision 
    setprecision(int __n) { return { __n }; }

template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
inline basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& 
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, _Setprecision __f)
{ 
    // Note you can alternatively call std::ostream::precision() function
    __os.precision(__f._M_n);
    return __os; 
}
```